# Why is my web app crashing after multiple GET requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, server, browser-cache

I have a web page that is running on a Python Bottle server.  I have a piece of JQuery that calls a GET request every second so I can refresh part of my page.  It works fine for about 8 hours..but then when I leave it running overnight, the browser crashes.

Here is my GET request (which is actually a .load() function so I can refresh just a part of my page) :

```
  $('#hiddenDataDiv').load(document.URL + " #hiddenDataDiv", function(result) {
    if (numberOfDivs > 0){
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfDivs; i++) {
    radioResult[i] = $('#data'+i).text();
  }}
});
```

This is called every second and sends a GET request to my Python Bottle server asking for the new data that is generated by my Python script.

I'm new to server side stuff, so am I causing some sort of memory leak?  Cache problems?  Is there a better way to refresh my page for long periods of time?
Also, is there something I can look for in my Google Chrome Inspector that could give me a clue?

**EDIT:  Full function code:**

```
function pollInputs(){ 

$('#hiddenDataDiv').load(document.URL + " #hiddenDataDiv", function(result) {
    if (numberOfDivs > 0){
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfDivs; i++) {
    radioResult[i] = $('#data'+i).text();
  }}
});


if (radioResult[0] != undefined){
      if (numberOfDivs > 0){
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfDivs; i++) {
  document.getElementById("input"+i).innerHTML = radioResult[i];
      }}
  }

}
```

Comment: `This is called every second` Hopefully your site has no users....You are going to be hammering it. How are you generating the requests? What are you doing with the response?

Comment: The server probably takes more than a second to respond, so you're getting a backlog, and it grows larger and larger.

Comment: @epascarello  The site is going to be on a local network so there would only be 1 or 2 users accessing the page.  The request is generated by the code I've posted.

Comment: @barmar - This sounds promising...what's a backlog and how can I prevent this?  Something like sending a GET, wait for response, then send next GET?

Comment: Open Developer Tools and take a look at the memory profiler

Comment: Imagine your job is fixing bicycles, and it takes you 2 hours to fix each bike. But new bikes come into the shop every hour. You can't keep up, and the pile of unrepaired bikes keeps getting larger and larger. That's a backlog.

Comment: @Barmar Makes sense.  Do you know how I could adjust my posted code to prevent the backlog?

Comment: Eventually you run out of room for all the bikes, and you have to stop allowing new customers until you fix everything you already have.

Comment: Instead of sending the requests every second, send the new request a second after processing the previous response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76212/discussion-between-alan-s-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't trigger the next request until after you've processed the previous one, to prevent a large backlog from building up.

```
function pollInputs(){ 

    $('#hiddenDataDiv').load(document.URL + " #hiddenDataDiv", function(result) { 
        if (numberOfDivs > 0){ 
            for (i = 0; i < numberOfDivs; i++) { 
                radioResult[i] = $('#data'+i).text(); 
            }
        } 
        setTimeout('pollInputs()', 1000); 
    }); 


    if (radioResult[0] != undefined){ 
        if (numberOfDivs > 0){ 
            for (i = 0; i < numberOfDivs; i++) { 
                document.getElementById("input"+i).innerHTML = radioResult[i]; 
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This answer is based on conjecture about what's killing the app. You might want to test it for a day before accepting.

Comment: I ran it again overnight...it worked on Chrome but my Internet Explorer (11) froze!  I could see that my python script was still running, but unfortunately, I wasn't able to click on Internet Explorer to check the console or anything.  Any advice on how I might be able to find the source of the issue?

Comment: Maybe open Developer Tools in IE before you start it up?